# Finding all values in between specific values in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, between

i have this dataframe.

```
df

  name  timestamp  year
0    A       2004  1995
1    D       2008  2004
2    M       2005  2006
3    T       2003  2007
4    B       1995  2008
5    C       2007  2003
6    D       2005  2001
7    E       2009  2005
8    A       2018  2009
9    L       2016  2018
```

What i am doing is that on the basis of first two entries in the df['timestamp']. I am fetching all the values from df['year'] which comes in between these two entries. Which in this case is (2004-2008).

```
y1 = df['timestamp'].iloc[0]
y2 = df['timestamp'].iloc[1]
movies = df[df['year'].between(y1, y2,inclusive=True )] 
movies 

  name  timestamp  year
1    D       2008  2004
2    M       2005  2006
3    T       2003  2007
4    B       1995  2008
7    E       2009  2005
```

This is working fine for me. But when i have greater value  in first index and lower in 2nd index (e.g. 2008-2004) the result is empty.

```
df

  name  timestamp  year
0    A       2008  1995
1    D       2004  2004
2    M       2005  2006
3    T       2003  2007
4    B       1995  2008
5    C       2007  2003
6    D       2005  2001
7    E       2009  2005
8    A       2018  2009
9    L       2016  2018
```

In this case i fetch nothing.

**Expected Outcome:**
What i want is if the values are greater or smaller i should get in-between values every time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include the progress (in code) you have made until now?

Comment: @Anteino Actually data is coming randomly in every iteration. What i have tried some conditions like `(df[(df['year'] <= y1) & (df['year'] >= y2)]` but in every iteration i am not sure 1st value is greater or smaller. So, i can't implement that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix that by changing just two lines of code:

```
y1 = min(df['timestamp'].iloc[0], df['timestamp'].iloc[1])
y2 = max(df['timestamp'].iloc[0], df['timestamp'].iloc[1])
```

in this way `y1` is always less or equal than `y2`.

However as @ALollz pointed out it is possible to save both computation and coding time by using

```
y1,y2 = np.sort(df['timestamp'].head(2))
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I was gonna suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that is certainly more efficient. I was just following OP script and being lazy. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Series.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) and [`Series.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
y1, y2 = df['timestamp'].head(2).agg(['min', 'max'])
movies = df[df['year'].between(y1, y2,inclusive=True )]
```

[out]

```
  name  timestamp  year
1    D       2004  2004
2    M       2005  2006
3    T       2003  2007
4    B       1995  2008
7    E       2009  2005
```